# TypeError: Cannot read property 'DETECTION_MODE' of undefined - 'react-native-awesome-card-io'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am running my test suit in this file :

```
import React from 'react'

import { PaymentDetails } from '../../../../app/screens/Account/components'
import { snapshot } from '../../../utils'


describe('PaymentDetails', () => {
  const paymentMethod = {
    accountName: 'Test Account',
    expMonth: 11,
    expYear: 2021,
    number: '4111111111111111',
    type: 'Visa',
    preferred: true,
  }

  test('snapshot = paymentDetails not empty', () => {
    snapshot(shallow(<PaymentDetails navigation={paymentMethod} />))
  })

  test('snapshot = paymentDetails empty', () => {
    snapshot(shallow(<PaymentDetails navigation={{}} />))
  })
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Do I need to mock this library? I have tried that but not much help  there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the file to `moduleNameMapper` in package.json fixed it for me.

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
   "react-native-awesome-card-io": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native-awesome-card-io/CardIOView.ios.js"
}
```

If you would like all the modules to be stubbed, you could write a regex to match those file names.

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('react-native-awesome-card-io', () => {
  return {
    CardIOUtilities: {
      preload: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response')),
    },
  }
})
```

This did the job for me. I did not need to map the module. So if you are mocking a native module make sure to use the original name for example CardIOUtility and not cardIOUtility alias.